# How to revert to Unity Lockscreen

Tags: 15.04, lock-screen

I installed xubuntu with the terminal command, and it changed my lockscreen. Can I get back to the original one? 
Thanks.
Pictures soon.

edit: I apparently can't add a comment, but it looks like the link Liso [posted](http://xubuntu.org/wp-content/uploads/2014/03/xubuntu_lock_light-locker.png)

I want it to look like [this](http://3.bp.blogspot.com/-MA8AAZ95A10/U0-byOqQQbI/AAAAAAAASQ8/cqlyO9f2Wrc/s1600/ubuntu14.04-lockscreen.png)

or the newer one.I don't have enough rep to post this link o_o

Comment: Is your lock screen like [this](http://xubuntu.org/wp-content/uploads/2014/03/xubuntu_lock_light-locker.png) ?

Comment: yes ^ I wonder why this didn't post before, I had enough characters. me being stupid again probably. Thanks for posting it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Launch terminal by <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd> and type this following to remove light-locker (xubuntu default lockscreen):

```
sudo apt-get remove light-locker
```

You may have to update the index :

```
sudo apt-get update
```

Reboot the system then

Comment: And why the reboot? This is not Windows.

Comment: Linux doesnt have to reboot ?

Comment: No, simply restart the service, I assume it's `lightdm`.